# How many numbers are there between $200$ and $400$ which are divisible by 11 and but not by 2?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many numbers are there between $200$ and $400$ which are divisible by 11 and  but not by 2?

How to count numbers that are divisible by them faster? I know the divisibility rule of $3$ and $11$ but how to count number between $200$ and $400$ faster and find the answer. I did not understand how to approach this question

Comment: Hint:  the smallest is $209$.  The others are $209+22k$ and you just need to compute the largest $k$.

Comment: For what purpose do you need the divisibility rule of $3$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at all the Multiples of 11 in between 200 and 400 and exclude all those who are a multiple of an even number. In other words look at all the multiples of 11 that can be found in the described range and exclude those that are the result of the multiplication of 11 with an even number. This should yield the result in no time.

The same idea laid out differently would be to find the smallest number that multiplied with 11 lies in the range and the largest number multiplied with 11 that lies in the range. Then count all the odd numbers between them (and including those two numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

- The number of multiples of $11$ less than or equal to $400$ is $\left\lfloor\frac{400}{11}\right\rfloor$.  The number of multiples of $11$ less than or equal to $200$ is $\left\lfloor\frac{200}{11}\right\rfloor$.  Therefore, the number of multiples of $11$ between $200$ and $400$ is 
  $$
  \left\lfloor\frac{400}{11}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{200}{11}\right\rfloor
  $$
- Do the same thing with $22$ and find the difference (the number divisible by $11$ minus the number divisible by $22$).

Answer (score 0):

We have the smallest value which satisfies this being $209=19\times 11$

We can then see that $20\times 11=2200$ which is divisible by $2$ but $21\times 11=231$  which isn't

Therefore all numbers of the form $209+22k$ will be divisible by $11$ and not by $2$. Now we want to find the largest value of $k$ such that $209+22k<400$

We can see that \begin{align}209+22k&<400\\
22k&<191\\
k&<\frac{191}{22}\\
k&<8.6\overline{18}\end{align}

Therefore there are $9$ values between $200$ and $400$ which are divisible by $11$ and not by $2$ (the value is not $8$, as we count $k=0$ as solution $1$ and $k=8$ is therefore solution $9$)

Namely, they are: $\{209,231,253,275,297,319,341,363,385\}$